# Converting mains powered monitor into DC

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, conversion, monitor

I have a DELL P2212H LED backlit monitor which runs on mains voltage. The power supply is internal. I need to run this from a 12V DC supply.

The main transformer has 3 outputs which goes through 3 separate diodes. After rectification, the voltages are
5V for the logic board
15V for the audio amplifier (which I don't need)
30V for the LED driver

I can generate 30 and 5 volts using 2 buck and boost converters. With the very limited knowledge I have with power supplies, I don't see any issue with connecting the + outputs from the converters to the cathodes of the diodes and - to the common ground. I can add diodes in the + outputs from the converters to be on the safe side.

I also want this to retain the ability to run from mains when needed.

Is there something I have overlooked? Is this doable?

[image: Proposed design]

Thanks

[image: Top]

[image: Bottom]

Comment: You have overlooked the current taken by the circuits on those power rails.

Comment: Why not just boost the 12V up to 100V or whatever the minimum input voltage is? There’s no power factor circuitry, so it will run on DC.

Comment: @Andyaka the current is less than 1 amp for both rails.

Comment: @Kartman Haven't thought about it. I was trying to reduce the number of voltage conversions though. The project will be powered by a battery, so efficiency is important. I'll check if I can find an efficient booster.